# php error MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT using meekrodb

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, meekro

I am building a PHP website using MeekroDB and PHPMailer.
I don't know why, but today I got this PHP error that is only on my desktop. 
On my laptop everything works fine.

I've tried to reinstall MySQL and delete all files and copies from my laptop.

The error is:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT' in /var/www/html/GIT/pressofficer/public/conf/configurations.php on line 6
Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT' in /var/www/html/GIT/pressofficer/public/libs/meekrodb.2.3.class.php on line 49
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/GIT/pressofficer/public/libs/meekrodb.2.3.class.php on line 169
```

Comment: Can you show your code too??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the unnecessary post but I installed **mysqli** again and it started working. 
Note that is **mysqli** not only mysql. 
I am don't know much about databases that's why I was very confused. 
Thanks anyway people.